# Connected components ocr in matlab(image processing)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to get connected components of an image and then run `ocr` for each connected component.This is my code-

```
clc
image=imread('im.png');
image=imcomplement(image);

[imx imy]=size(image);
n1=zeros(imx,imy);
symb=zeros(imx,imy);
lin=zeros(imx,imy);
L = bwlabel(image,8) ;%Calculating connected components
mx=max(max(L));
for i=1:mx
    [r,c] = find(L==i);
    n1=zeros(imx,imy);
    rc = [r c];
    [sx sy]=size(rc);

    for j=1:sx
        x1=rc(j,1);
        y1=rc(j,2);
        n1(x1,y1)=1;
    end

    figure,imshow(n1);title('components');
    r = ocr(n1,'TextLayout','Word')
    n=strtrim(r.Text); 
end
```

This is my input image-
[image]

One of the connected components which I get is this-
[image]

I get this when I display the components in 4th last line.But in the next line I dont get any result for the ocr of this component.So my question is why am I not getting `ocr` for this component whereas all other componets give some result in `ocr`.

If,instead of `im.png` I use this component as input in my very first line of the code-I get an ocr for this.Why is this happening?

**Edit**- If I use this component as input,I get the ocr.
[image]

Comment: When I use the binary image (corresponding to your "Component" image) I need to perform a slight morphological operation for `ocr` to actually detect something (the letter I). Otherwise I don't get anything. You're saying that in your case it does detect a letter without any manipulation?

Comment: I have editted my question.Actually I remove the white border from the component image using an external software and then use it.The `ocr` then detects this `|`

Comment: OCR: Optical Character Recognition. Unless what you are detecting are characters (e.g. "H" , "L" , "|" , ...) then its useless for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve (it was not very clear from your post). But if what you want is to extract the letters in a chemical formula the below code will do the trick.

```
I = imread('6oua6.png');
s = regionprops(~I,{'BoundingBox'});
for ii=1:numel(s)
  bb = s(ii).BoundingBox;
  if bb(4)<30 % enforce a limit to discard non-letters
    ocr(I,s(ii).BoundingBox, 'TextLayout', 'Block' )
    rectangle('Position',s(ii).BoundingBox+[-1 -1 2 2 ],'Edgecolor','y')
    pause
  end
end
```

The ocr will identify the letters correctly (at least from the image you supplied).
Binding them as further will just require you to construct some rules.

enjoy.